# Android BottomSheetDialogFragment hide/show behaviour

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I'm using Android's new support library 24.0.0 support library's `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.
Everything works fine except 2 things.
Previously, when I used plain old `DialogFragment` I used the below two properties to

1. remove black shadow.

   `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)`;
2. Prevent fragment dismissal when clicked in the outside region.

   `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

   `dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL`,

   ```
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)
   ```

;

What will be the equivalent to the above in case of bottom sheets fragment.
Below is my BottomSheetFragment code.

```
public class FullBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment
       {

    private BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.sheet, null);

        view.findViewById(R.id.fakeShadow).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        
        dialog.setContentView(view);
        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }

  

    
}
```